# tikzposter block numbering

Tags: numbering, tikzposter

Would anyone have an idea on how to number blocks in a tikzposter, according to the order with which they are read in the tex file ? Ideally the block number would be of the form i/n, where n is the total number of blocks and i the number of the current one.

The outlook would be something similar to the outlook of the following tex file;

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Template Poster}
\author{Author(s)}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
 \block{Basic Block}{Text \hfill (1/6)}
 \begin{columns}
\column{0.3333}% Width set relative to text width
\block{title}{\lipsum[1]
\hfill (2/6)}
\block{title}{\lipsum[2]
\hfill (3/6)}
\column{0.333}
\block{title}{\lipsum[3]
\hfill (4/6)}
\block{title}{\lipsum[1]
\hfill (5/6)}
\column{0.333}
\block{title}{\lipsum[4] 
\hfill(6/6)}

\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If a "block" is a custom environment, then you could define a new counter, and increment it every time the environment is used. It's hard to help you more specifically, so I suggest you add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Thank you, I added a MWE, and will try to build a counter myself. I just didn't see how to know the total number of blocks prior to the compilation.

Comment: You never know the total number before compiling, that's why you will need to compile twice: the total number will be deduced from the first compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`totcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/totcount) package; process the document twice to get the value for the total number of blocks.

In this first approach, you use the `\countblock` command for every block that you want to be numbered:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{myblocks}
\newcommand\countblock{%
  \stepcounter{myblocks}%
  \hfill (\themyblocks/\total{myblocks})%
}

\title{Template Poster}
\author{Author(s)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Basic Block}{Text \countblock}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3333}% Width set relative to text width
\block{title}{\lipsum[1]\countblock}
\block{title}{\lipsum[2]\countblock}
\column{0.333}
\block{title}{\lipsum[3]\countblock}
\block{title}{\lipsum[1]\countblock}
\column{0.333}
\block{title}{\lipsum[4]\countblock}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this second approach, the numbering is done automatically, by patching the `\block` command:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\block}
  {#3\par\normalsize}
  {#3\countblock\par\normalsize}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\newtotcounter{myblocks}
\newcommand\countblock{%
  \stepcounter{myblocks}%
  \hfill (\themyblocks/\total{myblocks})%
}

\title{Template Poster}
\author{Author(s)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Basic Block}{Text}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3333}% Width set relative to text width
\block{title}{\lipsum[1]}
\block{title}{\lipsum[2]}
\column{0.333}
\block{title}{\lipsum[3]}
\block{title}{\lipsum[1]}
\column{0.333}
\block{title}{\lipsum[4]}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```